# IE aborting external javascript file request

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, abort

This appears to be an IE issue only (code seems to work fine in Chrome).

Here is my code. It is saved as an HTML file:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

The issue is, that when I try to run this code in IE, the browser aborts the request. Please see the image below.

[image: Screen Capture]

To make matters worse. It randomly aborts. Sometimes it works and other times it does not.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you considered not supporting IE, Microsoft certainly has.

Comment: Is that the same domain from which your page is being served? This sounds more like a server issue than a JavaScript issue.

Comment: No right now I just have the page sitting on my desktop, and I open it in IE.

Comment: Please try to format your posts more carefully. 

Also if it works in Chrome, it does not mean it's only a IE issue - there are multiple other browsers out there. Checking at least 2 others may give you a first hint if it's a browser-specific problem or not. So far there is not enough information.

Comment: First go Tools>Internet Options>Advance tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save your changes. Blocked content, security warnings are now listed in the Console tab of the IE dev tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems pretty clear to me.  We ran into something similar a while back.  Check with your systems admin and see if they're doing any content filtering on this file type.  Sometimes IE can handle remote scripts a little differently than Chrome or Firefox.